# Cloud development

Tags: cloud

I need to develop a cloud-based solution. My questions are:

1. What will be the best solution, the easiest api?
2. For development I will need an hosting service of the same api, what hosting will be the best for development?

From googling around, I found right now the CloudStack to answer all my questions, but before diving into it, I will appreciate any comment.

Regards,
Meir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudStack is an IaaS solution.  If it answers your questions, then you're looking for a cloud that hosts VM rather than applications (Platform as a Service aka PaaS) or offers a specific service (Software as a Service aka SaaS).

Most IaaS clouds conform to the AWS (Amazon Web Services) model (e.g. OpenStack, CloudStack, the update to Windows Azure).  They have VMs, volumes, security groups, zones, etc.  The APIs are all RESTful.

Whether a cloud is the easiest depends on the quality of tools, client SDKs, your programming competency, and, most importantly, whether the API provides the specific IaaS functionality you are looking for.

E.g. CloudStack's original API has delegate administration, which allows one account to create resources on behalf of another.  For a Cloud Service Provider looking to offer their cloud to middlemen or outsources, delegated admin is very useful.  However, AWS has a very good .NET SDK, and a number of tools understand the EC2 API.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should try Microsoft Azure. There are SDK's for many languages (not only .NET) and whole API is RESTfull and well documented. You have many OS's for VMs in Your disposition and there is one thing You will be interested in I think: Azure have API building service, where You can develop Yur own API basing on Azure infrastructure and services. In example You can develop special API for automated processes based on Azure sevices like VMs. Those API will be handled by Azure itself, so You don't need to run special app to handle API requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking in terms of a better option I suggest Amazon AWS. However the other alternative can be Openstack and since openstack is a community many companies have opted it for example HP, Rackspace etc. These are good solutions in terms of Good API support as these have implementations in various languages. Also they have good services for hosting your application. Most importantly they provide good support.

However these are costly and I suggest you to try Azure as this is cheaper and if your project is smaller in size.

Go through the following links:-

- [azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/?b=16.33)
- [hpcloud](http://www.hpcloud.com/)
- [awscloud](https://aws.amazon.com/)